# SQL error (invalid input syntax for type double precision: "") when trying to run query

Tags: postgresql, null, sqldatatypes

I am working with world health's covid data for a projoect and have had no issues until this specific query keeps throwing the, invalid input syntax for double precision: "" error.
I should note that the tables were brought in from a CSV file and I am using postgresql.

Query throwing error:

```
select covid_deaths.continent, covid_deaths.location, covid_deaths.date, covid_deaths.population, covid_vacc.new_vaccinations,
SUM(covid_vacc.new_vaccinations::int) over (partition by covid_deaths.location 
order by covid_deaths.location, covid_deaths.date) as RollingPeopleVaccinated
from covid_deaths
join covid_vacc
on covid_deaths.location = covid_vacc.location and covid_deaths.date::date = covid_vacc.date::date
```

The line throwing the error is line 3, particularly the SUM(covid_vacc.new_vaccinations::int) portion. The new_vaccinations column in the covid_vacc table is VARCHAR datatype, and I know casting is not a great solution, but I am very much trying to avoid having to reimport all of the data from the excel sheet. Evne if I were to do this, not sure how to get all the datatypes correct and issues with null values cleared up.

I have tried not casing the new_vaccinations column as well as casting it as a few different datatypes. Have also tried running querys to alter the datatype of the new_vaccinations column, but I don't believe that is actually working. Fairly new to sql so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Update this column and replace all empty strings with a NULL

Comment: The issue is not with `NULL` values it is with empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nullif](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html) to convert empty strings to `NULL`. Use [trim](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) to shorten empty strings longer then `''` down to `''` for the `nullif` function.

```
Table "public.varchar_test"
   Column   |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 fld_1      | character varying(50) |           |          | 
 text_array | text[]                |           |          | 

insert into varchar_test(fld_1) values ('1'), (''), ('3');

select sum(fld_1::integer) from varchar_test ;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: ""


select sum(nullif(fld_1::integer, '')) from varchar_test ;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: ""


select sum(nullif(trim(fld_1), '')::integer) from varchar_test ;
 sum 
-----
   4
```

So in your case:

```
SUM(nullif(trim(covid_vacc.new_vaccinations), '')::integer)
```

FYI, the above will not deal with issues like:

```
select '1,000'::float;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "1,000"

select 'a'::float;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "a"
```

That means there still may be a need for data cleanup on the column.